# Xamarin.Android cannot use vector images

Tags: xamarin, svg, xamarin.android, android-vectordrawable

Recently I have faced with the issue that it is not possible to use vector drawable object from ***Native Android*** project in ***Xamarin.Android***:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error  No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/service_border')
```

Have somebody faced with the same issue ?

I have also tired to install ***Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable*** and enable it in ***MainActivity*** as:

```
AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true;
```

Vector Image has the following extension ***drawable/service_border.xml*** if it matter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="20dp"/>
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#CCCCCC"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: You haven't shown the code of your service_border and according to the error the problem is inside it, so without this the problem can't be solved.

Comment: @IvanIčin I have update question, but it is proper file because it opens and drawn properly in real Android Studio Project

Comment: check the xml is in `Resources/drawable` and the **Build Action** is `AndroidResource`

Answer (score 1):

1- You need first to convert your svg file to [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources) format, this tool ([svg2android](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/)) help you to do this.

2- Include the VectorDrawable xml file (e.g. mySVG.xml) into Resources/drawable folder.

3- Now you can display this VectorDrawable directly with an ImageView:

```
var resId = Resources.GetIdentifier("mySVG", "drawable", "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME");
myImageView.SetImageResource(resId);
```

I hope this help.

Comment: You did not get ... I've already put in Resources/drawable proper VectorDrawable file, because it is opened in Android Studio Project properly ... but anyway an issue exists

Comment: The xml file you have posted in your question is not a VectorDrawable file.

Comment: But it opens properly in Android Studio Project ? Why isn't it a proper xml ?

Comment: Yes, seems you are right it is ShapeDrawable ... but how to open ShapeDrawable properly ?

Comment: It is a proper drawable file but not a VectorDrawable, may be you use it as a normal drawable, I can't tell until see your code.

Comment: `but how to open ShapeDrawable properly`, It depends on how you need to use it

Comment: I want to use it as background android:background="@drawable/service_border" in layout as in Native Android Application ... But when I put it in the same folder as in Native Android it shows me an error as in question

Comment: You may need to include the file in your project, I assume that you can show the hidden files in solution explorer window, right click service_border.xml and select "Include in project"

Answer (score -1):

Your xml file is not a vector drawable file. you need to convert it. go to https://svg2vector.com/

convert any image and see changes.

see, if your vector xml file looks identical. obiously it is not identical. so you need to convert it